# Turning this list off a website into a python list

Tags: python, list, passwords

https://github.com/danielmiessler/SecLists/blob/master/Passwords/10k_most_common.txt

What would be the most efficient way of turning this list into a python list, I only really need the top 100.

Thanks, leon.

FYI, I have looked around the website and have found many thing relating to multiline lists but nothing has helped me.

Comment: Read the file in, then split on newlines.

Comment: What do you mean by "most efficient"? Least programming time? Fewest number of lines? If you mean those, use Matteo Secco's answer. Least amount of input/output? If those, use a few more lines to read only the first 100 lines. Least execution time? That depends on your environment. Do you want code that reads only the first 100 lines?

Comment: Efficient factors in everything.

Comment: Practically never can code be efficient in everything. As the saying about programming goes: "Good, fast, cheap. Pick two." The current favorite answer is excellent in many ways but poor in input/output amounts.

Answer (score 2):

```
yourlist = open("10k_most_common.txt", "r").read().split("\n")[:100]
```

- *open()*  : opens the file; takes two arguments, the file name, and what you want to do with it, in this case you want to *r* read it
- *read()*  : so now you have the file object, but you need what's written inside of it; with the function read() you get all the content of the file as a string
- *split()* : it divides the string by the argument, in this case *\n* (the newlines), so the string becomes a list
- *[:100]*   : With this, you can specificates what part of the list you want. So *[:100]* is the same as *[0:100:1*], that means: start from index zero, arrive to index 100, with an intervall between element of one (so every element from 0 to 100)

If it is too hard to you to understand you can use this longer form:

```
file = open("10k_most_common.txt", "r")
string = file.read()
yourlist = string.split("\n")[:100]
```

Comment: I have no idea what this does nor does it have any functionality, could you please be more specific in what it does?

Comment: Better to use `with` and `readlines` which returns a list without the need to explicitly call `split`. It is also preferable to not override the name `list`.

Comment: @leon Is it ok now?

Comment: @MatteoSecco Don't have a variable called list. You're shadowing the built in function.

Comment: @Carcigenicate thank you! I always forgot python's arrays are called list.

Comment: but how do I open the file, I dont even know how to download it off github haha, and wouldI be using a filepath like C:\Leon\Desktop\10k_most_common.txt

Comment: @Yes, or you can just move it to the same folder of your code, so you can find it just saying "10k_most_common.txt" instead of the full path. To download the file just press "raw", it opens an html file with only the 10k passwords, so you just have to press CTRL+A and then CTRL+V in an empty .txt file

Comment: file = open ("C:\\Users\\Leon\\Desktop\\top1000passwords.txt", "r")
file.read()
yourlist = file.split("\n")[:1000]
print(yourlist)

Comment: however errors as Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:/thingy.py", line 3, in <module>
    yourlist = file.split("\n")
AttributeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'split'

Comment: @leon Sorry, I've done a little mistake. Now the code is working

Comment: I was trying to use this code but it kept putting \n at the end of the words making them uncomparable file = open ("C:\\Users\\Leon\\Desktop\\top1000passwords.txt", "r")

cpwords = file.readlines()